# Why are notifications on MacBook Pro slower than on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, macbook-pro, notifications, facebook

I have an iPhone 4 on iOS 6.1.3 and a MBP 13' 2012 i5 on OSX 10.8.3 connected to the same WiFi network. Now whenever a notification comes, be it Facebook or Messages (exceptions: Reminder and Calendar), iPhone alerts me before the Mac does.

I checked, but couldn't find a place in the Mac where I can edit these settings to make checking for notifications more frequent.

Can you tell me how do I make it better. Because the lag is sometimes more than 30 seconds.

Comment: Are chat messages in Messages being delivered slowly on the mac?  I have both open simultaneously most of the day with less than a second between delivery on each platform.

Comment: Thats what is unusual on my Mac. Is it because I use Gmail and facebook chats through the Messages app.(i.e. chat.facebook.com via Jabber). If it is, it should be definitely improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to depend on how your Notifications are configured. If you have your notifications set to Banners, the order will be Watch first, Phone second, Mac last (if unopened on Watch and Phone). If you have your notifications set to Alerts the order will be whichever device is open currently and then the rest of the devices will not receive the alerts. Thus if your Mac is open you will receive an Alert and none of your other devices will receive it. However if you have Banners on then the notification will flow down the line of iOS devices until you open it.